# How to prove $\left\{x : x∈A\right\} = A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove $\left\{x : x∈A\right\} = A$?

$\left\{x : x∈A\right\}$ and $A$ are sets.

I tried to understand it formal via logic but I can only understand this intuitively.

Comment: What have you attempted in the direction of writing a formal proof? What your thoughts are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\set}{\{ x~|~x \in A \}}$
You can simply show it under [Axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) noting [Set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate).

1. First, assume $x \in \set$. Then, $x \in A$.
2. Assume $x \in A$. Then, $x \in \set$.

By the axiom of extensionality, they are identical.

Comment: How to prove  x∈A ⇔ x ∈ {x | x∈A}?

Comment: @stack I used rules of inference called conditional introduction and biconditional introduction. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_conditionals. If you assume $P$ and eventually get $Q$, you have $P \Rightarrow Q$. Moreover, if you also get $Q \Rightarrow P$, you will finally have $P \Leftrightarrow Q$.

Comment: @stack More rigorously I also used $\forall$ elimination and introduction.

Comment: I know the meaning of the symbols like ⇒ and ⇔. But I can't understand why x∈{x | x∈A} ⇒ x∈A and x∈A ⇒ {x | x∈A}. I can just understand it intuitively.

Comment: @stack By the set-builder notation, any element $x$ that satisfies $x \in A$ is an element of the set $\{x~|~x \in A\}$. And any element in $\{x~|~x \in A\}$ must satisfy $x \in A$.